# Allocate value of referred row to previous row

Tags: r, data-science

Hi I will illustrate what I am trying to do as it is easier to understand my demand with an example.

I have a data frame : df

```
ID  Thought    NewThought
1   0          0
2   0          0
3   0          0
4   0          0
5   1          0
6   0          0
7   1          0
```

I would like to copy the value of thought when it is greater than 0 to the previous row in the column NewThought. Which would give us:

```
ID  Thought    NewThought
1   0          0
2   0          0
3   0          0
4   0          1
5   1          0
6   0          1
7   1          0
```

I have tried this, but it is not working

```
setDT(Df)[which(Thought > 0)-1, NewThought := Thought[+1]]
```

Comment: `setDT(Df)[which(Thought > 0)-1, NewThought := 1]`?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 df$NewThought[which(df$Thought>0) - 1] <- df$Thought[df$Thought > 0] 
 df
  ID Thought NewThought
1  1       0          0
2  2       0          0
3  3       0          0
4  4       0          1
5  5       1          0
6  6       0          1
7  7       1          0
```

Comment: This worked for me, had no issues thank you, in some levels I will be aible to give a point

Answer (score 1):

Just shift the column up a notch...

```
df$NewThought <- c(df$Thought[-1],0)

df
  ID Thought NewThought
1  1       0          0
2  2       0          0
3  3       0          0
4  4       0          1
5  5       1          0
6  6       0          1
7  7       1          0
```

In response to the follow-up question, looking at 3 previous rows, you could do

```
df$NewThought3 <- c(sapply(1:(nrow(df)-1),function(i) 
                    max(df$Thought[(i+1):max(i+3,nrow(df))],na.rm=TRUE))
                    ,0)

df
  ID Thought NewThought NewThought3
1  1       0          0           1
2  2       0          0           1
3  3       0          0           1
4  4       0          1           1
5  5       1          0           1
6  6       0          1           1
7  7       1          0           0
```

Comment: Your answer partially helped me, thank you. Although how could I do this for the 3 previous rows? So that in the example row 2, 3, 4 have the value of Thought [5].

Comment: See revised answer above

Comment: Thank you, although I am facing a new problem now but will try to figure it out on my own. Thanks a lot !